# comparing params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing

```
if params[:type] = "Type A"
   # do something
end
if params[:type] = "Type B"
   # do something
end
```

But I think that is wrong. I should be using `==`

However that gives me error:

You have nil object when you didn't expect it

What is the best way to do this in rails?

All I am doing is getting a radio button variable from a form and doing logic based on its value (either Type A or Type B)

Comment: Unless you're doing something strange with `params` *before* this block of code, the `nil object` error is definitely not coming from the comparison. It's coming from what happens in that second block or the fact that neither block is being run. (When you use `=`, the first `if` will always evaluate to `true` so the first block will always be evaluated.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Preamble

```
class Hash
  def try(arg)
    self[arg] rescue nil
  end
end
```

## Your way

```
if params.try(:type) == "Type A"
    # do
elsif params.try(:type) == "Type B"
    # do
end
```

## DRY

```
case params.try(:type)
when "Type A"
    # do
when "Type B"
    # do
else
    # default do
end
```

Comment: Object#try works on instances of ActiveRecord models because they all provide *methods* for each field in the row of the relation they represent. It does however not work on a hash as you have to use Hash#[]/Hash#fetch to access the hash content.

Comment: The solution does not throw an exception by the way because `params` does have the method `type`, which HashWithdifferentAccess/Hash inherited from Object: It is a deprecated alias for Object#class.

See http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000349

Comment: `case params.try(:type)` didn't work for me, but `case params[:type]` did work (I don't understand why, but it took an hour to find that variation, as in @MBO reply)

Answer (score 3):

You're sure it should be `params[:type]`? First, check your logs to see what is inside params before you access action in controller.

To check multiple choices you can use switch construct:

```
case params[:type]
when "Type A"
  # do sth
when "Type B"
  # do sth
else # not A nor B, can be nil
  # do nothing
end
```

And if you need to deeper inside params then you can use if/else:

```
if params[:type] && params[:type][:value] == "sth"
  # do sth
elsif params[:type] && params[:type][:value] == "..."
  # do sth
end
```

And check where you get your error from, because in Ruby you can easily compare nil and String, so it's not because of using `==` in your example.